# SQL Server can't find user created function

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions

I have multiple Account Type codes stored in a VARCHAR field separated by semi-colons. I need the names associated with the Codes in a single string.

I am trying to use a pair of functions.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[AcctTypCodesMulti](@strCodes VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS table
AS
Return
    (select [Account Type] from dbo.Account_Type Join string_split(@strCodes, ';') as TypeCodes on dbo.Account_Type.[Option] = TypeCodes.value)
```

which is called by:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[AcctTypNamesMulti](@string VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @strvalue VARCHAR(MAX)
    select @strvalue = @string
    select @string = string_agg([dbo].[AcctTypCodesMulti](@strvalue),';')
    RETURN @string
END
```

When I try to call this:

```
dbo.AcctTypNamesMulti(acc.accounttypemulti) AS [Account Type Name Multi]
```

I get an error as follows.

> Cannot find either column [dbo] or the user defined function or aggregate "dbo.AcctTypCodesMulti" or the name is ambiguous.

Any ideas why I am getting the error?  I do have another working solution, but it uses a temp table and while what I have is OK, I am worried about performance if data volumes grow.

The function does appear under table functions in `\Programmability\Functions`

I tried combining the two functions, but `STRING_AGG` won't allow a sub-query in the parameter and I can't put a USE statement in a function.  Bother functions are in the same database and I have check other DBs on same server and I didn't accidentally create a duplicate there.

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: there are scalar functions that are called: `select dbo.FunctionName(param1,param2)` and table functions that returns a table, these must be called as a from: `select * from dbo.FunctionName(param1, param2) x`

Comment: @siggemannen

I tried changing it to read

BEGIN
    DECLARE (at)strvalue VARCHAR(MAX)
    select (at)strvalue = (at)string
    select (at)string = string_agg(select * from [dbo].[AcctTypCodesMulti](@strvalue),';')
    RETURN (at)string
END

I got syntax errors and a warning saying "Select statement included within a function cannot return data to a client."

Answer (score 0):

The proper code would be:

```sql
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[AcctTypCodesMulti](@strCodes VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS table
AS
Return
    select at.[Account Type]
    from dbo.Account_Type at
    Join string_split(@strCodes, ';') as TypeCodes
      on at.[Option] = TypeCodes.value

GO
```

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[AcctTypNamesMulti](@string VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(max)
AS
BEGIN
    select  @string = string_agg(Account_type,';')
    FROM    [dbo].[AcctTypCodesMulti](@string) x
    
    RETURN @string
END
```

But your whole function idea won't work anyway, because STRING_SPLIT doesn't respect positions of a string unless you are running on SQL Server 2022+ and pass a positional parameter.
So if you pass codes: `code1; code2; code3` it won't necessary returns the `name1, name2, name3` in the same order (even if it might look like it does).

You need to return a positional id like 1, 2, 3 in AcctTypCodesMulti so that you can ORDER by it in the STRING_AGG, like: `STRING_AGG(Account_type,';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY positional_id)`

There are custom split functions you can use which return an extra positional arguments, search for them in stackoverflow, but I would suggest abandoning the whole thing until you have a better grasp of the basics.

Comment: I don't care about the order of the returned values in this case, so you solution works and educated me on what I was doing wrong.

Comment: `STRING_SPLIT` does now support an `ordinal` column

Answer (score 0):

Following @siggemannen help.

The following works and is reduced to a single function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[AcctTypeNamesMultiV2](@string VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(max)  
AS  
BEGIN  
    select @String = string_agg([Account Type],';') from (select [Account Type]  
    FROM dbo.Account_Type  Join  
    string_split(@String, ';') as TypeCodes on  
    dbo.Account_Type.[Option] = TypeCodes.value ) x  
     
    RETURN @String
end
GO
```